# WireMock returns image that's corrupt

Tags: jetty, wiremock

I've recorded a mock through WireMock that contains an image in the body. When I try to get the stub using Postman the response back is an image that won't load and the size of the content is roughly 20-50% larger than when I get the same image from the production server. In Google Chrome it says `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg`.

I can't tell if this is an underlying issue with Jetty or WireMock. I read some related [chatter on the user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/wiremock-user/wiremock$20images%7Csort:relevance/wiremock-user/dtH8eFhi9SQ/Mf0JMsP4AwAJ) about images being returned incorrectly, but I've tried the suggestion of removing the mapping stub and just keeping the __file - no luck. This seems like an encoding issue, but I don't know how to debug it further.

Comment: Do you have a test case you could share? Would be great to be able to confirm the new code doesn't suffer from this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you can hang in there until next week we're putting the finishing touches on a brand new recorder and I've been specifically working through the encoding issues the current recorder suffers from.

Meanwhile, you might want to try turning off gzip in your client code.

Comment: Thanks @Tom I saw the work going on the repo but didn't want to ask how long until it ships 